# Unix find on a 6T disk taking 14hrs : csh

Tags: unix, find, csh

I have a csh script with the below lines to capture user name, file and size in a given disk. This was working fine until it hit capacity limit on a 6T disk which has over 5.5million files for just 1 user. How do I go about modifying this line to speed up runtime. Currently takes 14-15hrs on this line.

```
set len = ()
foreach i ( `find $cwd -not -path '*/\.*' -printf "%u\n" | sort -u` ) 
        set len = ($len:q `find $cwd -user $i | wc -l`)
end
find $cwd -printf "%u %s\n" | awk '{user[$1]+=$2;count[$1]++}; END{ for( i in user) printf "%s%-13s%5s%-0.2f%s%5s%7s\n","", i, "", user[i]/1024**3,"GB", "", count[i]}'| sort -nk2 -r
```

Comment: You probably don't need to run that `find` in the loop, you can just get one long list of all files with all users and filesizes, and count it from there (e.g. only run one `find`). That can be done a lot easier with a tool like Python or Perl btw. That said, if you've got 6T of data in >5 million of files then it'll probably take a while no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

If you use command execution to provide shell input, you are basically creating a 5.5 million times file path length shell script line. This needs to be parsed etc.

So the answer is to re-write your scripts differently. Either use pipes, e.g.

```
find ... | {shell code}
```

or

```
find ... -exec {script} \;
```

A common way to express the first is:

```
find ... | xargs ...
```

The beauty of xargs is that it can run a number of commands in parallel with `-P maxprops`, speeding up your calculation.

Another tip is not to use `csh` (or any shell really) for such computationally intensive scripts.

The task you are performing here is more suited to a scripting language such as Perl or Python.